# fast gradient method for convex piecewise linear function

Tags: convex-optimization

What is the state of art gradient based algorithms in convex optimization solving non-smooth piece-wise linear functions? Thank you.

EDIT: It is different from one of my previous post in the sense that here, I am focusing on piece-wise linear functions:D

Comment: possible duplicate of [state of art non smooth convex optimization](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/state-of-art-non-smooth-convex-optimization)

Comment: Did you post the same question twice?

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases I can think of (assuming minimization):

- your non-smooth piecewise linear function is convex, in which case, standard reformulations result in a convex program (or even a linear program), so you can consult a textbook in convex optimization such as the one by Boyd to find applicable algorithms.
- your non-smooth piecewise linear function is nonconvex; then the reformulation I mentioned above doesn't apply, and you probably need to provide more about the problem structure.

Comment: My problem is convex. The problem is that, I intuitively think I shall use Nesterov's accelerated gradient method... But the book hasn't introduced that... And I am wondering whether there is even improvements on Nesterov's method to specially tackle convex piece-wise linear problems...